How the explanation about single droplet explains the formation of entire rainbow
The explanation of reflection and refraction with single drop is understood.
Now, rain is some kind of rows of drops. I would have understood how the explanation of one drop can be extended to a row of drops.
But each row should create its own rainbow and thus we should have rainbow below rainbow below rainbow.
Can anyone explain this thing?

Note that the light for the rainbow comes out a specific angles. The light from the sun comes in at a specific angle. You only see a rainbow from a small portion of all the drops way over there that have the angles all working out properly. The refraction from other drops is seen from other positions.

This question is similar to: How does a rainbow show all of its colours?. Note that an important fact is that the eye only processes light which enters it. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not just one raindrop that makes a rainbow, but a lot of them all contribute to the same visible effect. Even a hosepipe spray can make a rainbow, whose position is even more strangely elusive than a rainbow created by rain.

@Farcher yes, you are right, thank you

Also, to get the colours not to wash out by overlapping, Lewin specifically mentions that the reflected light has a spike in intensity at those angles you worked out. So that then the one colour satisfying the angles will be strong enough to overcome the stray light overlapping.

One way to see this is that if you live somewhere where the mornings are cool and sunny with dew on the grass, then each dew-drop acts like a tiny refractive spherical prism. If you get up close you can see each drop glowing with a very pure single frequency colour. As you move your head, teh drop's colour will change across teh spectrum from purple, through blue, green, yellow, orange, to red. Very pretty effect.

Every rainbow is personal.

It is like this (extra words added because a picture appears not to be worth 1000 of them).

